# Laravel 5 shows error even through it debug mode is set to false and env to production

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.5 I have set both my debug mode to false and env to be production.

Now I make a API call to my app, but it still returns the full 500 error.

I added a column that doesnt exist in a query still outputs this error to the user:

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column xxxx..
"exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
```

I have also tried to do php artisan cache:clear but same result.
I am running laravel through Valet if it matters

Comment: have you restarted the server??

Comment: Is your configuration cached? The cached config will store the values read from your `.env` file, rather than fetching them dynamically. If you changed `.env`, you'll want to regenerate your config cache.

Comment: @AkenRoberts I tried php artisan cache:clear and also tried to write them without suing env file but same thing

Comment: @SalmanZafar I tried php artisan cache:clear and also tried to write them without suing env file but same thing, just tried to run it again with restarted server but same result